# OpenStack With Manila Installation Fails from Devstack

Tags: installation, openstack, devstack

Trying to  install OpenStack Kilo version with Manila Features enabled . However the installation fails with errors.

Environment :

Operating System : RHEl 7 enabled with RHN

Devstack GIT used :

git clone -b stable/kilo  https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git

Information of localrc used :

```
***************************** localrc ****************************************

# Credentials
DATABASE_PASSWORD=devstack
ADMIN_PASSWORD=devstack
SERVICE_PASSWORD=devstack
SERVICE_TOKEN=devstack
RABBIT_PASSWORD=devstack
GUEST_PASSWORD=devstack
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=devstack
RABBIT_HOST=127.0.0.1
LIBVIRT_TYPE=qemu
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=127.0.0.1:9292
SERVICE_PASSWORD=devstack
ENABLED_SERVICES=key,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,n-sch,n-novnc,n-xvnc,n-cauth
#glance
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,g-api,g-reg
#cinder
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,cinder,c-sch,c-api,c-vol,c-bak
#manila
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,manila,m-api,m-sch,m-shr
#others
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,horizon,rabbit,mysql,tempest
#neutron needs for manila
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc,q-agt,q-dhcp,q-l3,q-meta,neutron
#
LOGDAYS=1
LOGFILE=$DEST/devstack.log
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
RECLONE=yes
API_RATE_LIMIT=False

Q_PLUGIN=ml2
ENABLE_TENANT_VLANS=True
ML2_VLAN_RANGES=physnet1:100:4000
PHYSICAL_NETWORK=physnet1
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=openvswitch
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_TYPE_DRIVERS=flat,vlan,vxlan
SHARE_BACKING_FILE_SIZE=8G
FLAT_INTERFACE=eno1

MANILA_REPO_ROOT=openstack

enable_plugin manila https://github.com/openstack/manila

****************************************************************************************************

Installation Errors :

2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | ++ user_role_id=de7a755f4a604c3c843f912d3daa8bc2
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | ++ echo de7a755f4a604c3c843f912d3daa8bc2
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | de7a755f4a604c3c843f912d3daa8bc2
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | ++ [[ stack == \u\n\s\t\a\c\k ]]
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | ++ [[ stack == \c\l\e\a\n ]]
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + [[ stack == \s\o\u\r\c\e ]]
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + [[ stack == \o\v\e\r\r\i\d\e\_\d\e\f\a\u\l\t\s ]]
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + run_plugins stack post-config
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + local mode=stack
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + local phase=post-config
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + local plugins=,manila
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + local plugin
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + for plugin in '${plugins//,/ }'
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + local dir=/opt/stack/manila
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + [[ -f /opt/stack/manila/devstack/plugin.sh ]]
2015-06-26 12:19:28.862 | + source /opt/stack/manila/devstack/plugin.sh stack post-config
2015-06-26 12:19:29.109 | 'oslo.service' is not in global-requirements.txt
2015-06-26 12:19:29.117 | Error on exit
***********************************************************************************************
```

However, the installation works perfectly fine if following git is used

git clone -b master https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git

Appreciate if there's any help .

Regards, 
Amit

Comment: Kindly check the [oslo_concurrency] section under the controller and compute nodes of your deployment (in the file neutron.conf). You must have **lock_path** configured. One reason of facing this problem can be because the latest guides or repositories do not contain this configuration by mistake.